# Snowflake Loading Flat Files

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My company is looking to possibly migrate to Snowflake from SQL Server.  From what i've read on snowflake documentation, flat files (CSV) can get uploaded and set into a staging table then use COPY INTO that loads data into physical table.

example: `put file://c:\temp\employees0*.csv @sf_tuts.public.%emp_basic;`

My question is, can this be automated via a job or script within snowflake? this includes the copy into command.

Comment: Yes, it can be done using [Snowpipe](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-intro.html)

Comment: Also by using a stored procedure, or by using linked tasks…

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to automate jobs in Snowflake as already commented by others. Putting your code in a Stored Procedure and call it via a [Task](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html) in schedule is an option.

There is also a command line interface in Snowflake called [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html).